# Threading issue..inner class..field

Tags: java, thread-safety, field, inner-classes, performance-testing

I'm having a threading issue..

I'm doing a lookup using an inner class..I've been reading up on how to do this properly and everything points at using a field..in my case " boolean verify".

Basically if the object is there. I declare the field true and return the value. The problem is, during performance testing the same method in the same object is being called in several threads at the same time and the effects have been funny. (I'm guessing because of the pause() (which waits 10ms))

So in thread A..the objects there so it declares the field true..waits 10ms..
in thread B..the objects not there but because of the wait and that the same field is being accessed it returns a true anyway.

I'm in trouble here :(

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

```
boolean verify; 
  public boolean lookupAndVerify(String id) throws InterruptedException
  {
    final String key = id;
    PastryIdFactory localFactory = new rice.pastry.commonapi.PastryIdFactory(env);
    final Id lookupKey = localFactory.buildId(key);
    Past p = (Past) apps.get(env.getRandomSource().nextInt(apps.size()));
    p.lookup(lookupKey, new Continuation<PastContent, Exception>()
    {
      public void receiveResult(PastContent result)
      {
        P2PPKIContent content = (P2PPKIContent) result;
        if(content !=null){
        verify = true; 
        }
      }
      public void receiveException(Exception result)
      {
        System.out.println("Error looking up " + lookupKey);
      }
    });
    pause();
    return verify;
  }
```

Comment: Just thinking to myself while reading back over the question..Maybe I should create an accessor object. I will make a new one every time I call the lookupAndVerify(). This way there will only be a new object for each lookup and the threads shouldn't be effected?

Comment: im not really sure what your trying to do here, it seems you are using a anonymous inner class as some sort of listener.

This code looks very messy, what are you trying to do? make a method that blocks execution until a thread receives some result? a anonymous inner class is definitely not the way to go. especially not in a multi threaded environment.

you can use a thread to do the receiving and notify other threads if a result is ready to proccess.

Comment: @Conor: If you're talking about essentially using a wrapper that has a `set` method on it, this would work, but you still have the problem of `pause()` being a lousy synchronization mechanism.  Ideally, the wrapper would also allow you to block until the value is set, and that's where `Future<T>` (and my answer) come in.

Comment: p.lookup is part of the free pastry api. As far as i can see it is the only way to do a lookup. And looking at examples this is how people seem to go with it.

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes Mark your suggestion makes a lot of sense. This is my first time doing performance testing with threading being a major issue. I was unsure of how to implement an asynchronous call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a bit of research into asynchronous calls.  Pausing for a certain number of milliseconds is *not* a safe way to ensure that your callback has been called, and as you said, making `verify` a field will not work if the object is shared by multiple threads.

One option you could use is a [`Future<Boolean>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (in this case, [`SettableFuture<Boolean>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html) from the Guava libraries is convenient):

```
final SettableFuture<Boolean> verify = new SettableFuture<Boolean>();

p.lookup(lookupKey, new Continuation<PastContent, Exception>()
{
  public void receiveResult(PastContent result)
  {
    P2PPKIContent content = (P2PPKIContent) result;
    if(content !=null){
       verify.set(true);
    }
  }
  public void receiveException(Exception result)
  {
    System.out.println("Error looking up " + lookupKey);
    verify.set(false);
  }
});

return verificationQueue.get(); //this will block until verify has been set!
```

A `Future<T>` is a concurrency construct that will have a value *some time in the future*. As soon as you ask for its value, however, it will block until it has a value.

### Edit

If for some reason you can't pull in Guava, a slightly less intuitive solution is to use a [`BlockingQueue<Boolean>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) with a capacity of 1:

```
final BlockingQueue<Boolean> verificationQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Boolean>(1);

p.lookup(lookupKey, new Continuation<PastContent, Exception>()
{
  public void receiveResult(PastContent result)
  {
    P2PPKIContent content = (P2PPKIContent) result;
    if(content !=null){
       verificationQueue.put(true);
    }
  }
  public void receiveException(Exception result)
  {
    System.out.println("Error looking up " + lookupKey);
    verificationQueue.put(false);
  }
});

return verify.take(); //blocks until an item has been put on the queue
```

If you're going to do this, it's worth encapsulating the queue in a class with a more readable API.

Comment: Great..thank you..I tried something similar using an array..but found out fairly quickly this was not a good way to go..I'll get working..much appreciation

Comment: In case anyones reading up on this..I had a little difficulty with the first approach Mark listed..Second one worked perfectly straight away..Thanks a lot @Mark helped me greatly

Answer (score 0):

You should make one of these objects (the class name is omitted, so I can't say specifically) for every thread, if it doesn't *need* to be shared.